# Distributing Together = Converging Together?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X_{n}$ , $Y_{n}$ be a series of real valued random variables which distributes the same, i.e:
$$
P(X_{n}\in A)=P(Y_{n}\in A)
$$
and lets assume $Y_{n}$ converges almost surely to a constant limit $a$  , does it imply convergence almost surely?

I know this implies that $X_{n}$ converges to $a$ in probability but I need almost sure convergence, so what other conditions may show it?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't think so. We do get that $X_n \to a$ in probability but I'm not sure we get almost sure convergence.

Comment: I think that's not true in the general case but I though that if the limit is a constant then maybe the almost sure limit does exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[0,1]$ with Borel sets and Lebesgue measure serve as probability space.

Define the sequence $X_n$ as indicators $\mathbf1_{[0,1]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/2]},\mathbf1_{[1/2,1]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/3]},\mathbf1_{[1/3,2/3]},\mathbf1_{[2/3,1]},\dots$

Define the sequence $Y_n$ as indicators $\mathbf1_{[0,1]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/2]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/2]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/3]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/3]},\mathbf1_{[0,1/3]},\dots$

Then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same distribution and $Y_n$ converges to $0$ a.s. but $X_n$ does not.